# How do I fix the admin login dialog box?

Tags: macos

Ever since upgrading to Yosemite, I've had an issue with the admin login screen. It looks like this:

[image]

It's not a huge problem because I know what it is and I just enter my password and move on. But does anyone have ideas on how to get this fixed other than reinstall Yosemite?

Comment: Try using Safe mode log in.

Comment: Did you recently install a font to replace system font?